# How do you obtain algebraically the following limit?

Tags: limits, infinity

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{64x^{12}+45x^5-100}}{6x^6-x^4+14}$$
What I mean by algebraically, is by doing transformations or other things, not just evaluating the function with excessively big numbers.

Also, I know that the limit is $\displaystyle\frac{4}{3}$. I just want to know how to obtain it. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In order to obtain any help, it is advisable to provide your attempts so that we can better help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "algebraically"? For calculating such limits, only the highest exponents and their scalars are of greater interest.

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $x^6$.  You have $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt{64+45\cdot\frac{1}{x^7}-100\cdot\frac{1}{x^{12}}}}{6-\frac{1}{x^2}+14\cdot\frac{1}{x^6}}$.  Can you continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard method when tackeling such limits, is to factor out the highest powers of $x$.

You have

$\sqrt{64x^{12}+45x^5-100}=\sqrt{x^{12}\left(64+\dfrac{45}{x^7}-\dfrac{100}{x^{12}}\right)}=x^6\sqrt{64+\dfrac{45}{x^7}-\dfrac{100}{x^{12}}}$

and for the denominator

$x^6\left(6-\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{14}{x^6}\right)$.

Now you cancel these powers.
In this case it is kind off a coincidence, that the power of $x$ equals. This is also the most interesting case.

The idea behind this "method" is that to use the limit theorems, and now we can see the limit in the numerator and denominator easily, as the summands are either constant, or null sequences.

So the limit in the numerator is $\sqrt{64}$.

The limit in the denominator is $6$.

Then the limit of the fraction is $8/6=4/3$.